# Formal power series ring & completion

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

I encountered the following passage in Matsumura's *Commutative Ring Theory* :

A a Noetherian ring, $B=A[[x]]$ a formal power series ring. $M\subset B$ a maximal ideal, $\mathfrak{m}=M\cap A$. Then $(B_{M})^{\mbox{^}}=(A_{\mathfrak{m}})\mbox{^}[[x]]$, where ^ indicate $M$-adic and $\mathfrak{m}$-adic completions, respectively.

It's not immediately clear to me why this is the case. How should I go about proving this?
Thanks!

Comment: The universal property of the completion?

Comment: The content is the assertion that $x \in M$, from which the rest is then clear (by either Litt's suggestion or inspection of constructions). So you should prove that $x$ lies in every maximal ideal (i.e., is in the "Jacobson radical").  There is a well-known criterion for such membership involving units...

Comment: "Daniel" is fine by the way, rather than "Litt."  And if the Jacobson radical feels too high-powered, one might proceed by noting that if x is not in M, then it descends to a unit in the quotient (the quotient being a field).  But it's easy to see this can't happen.  (This is essentially the same, of course, but has essentially no prerequisites.)

Comment: Daniel: Thanks for fleshing out the argument to which I was alluding in my final sentence. 

Comment: I happened to know that x should be in every maximal ideal of A[[x]] but I don't see how that helps. If I write down the completions using inverse limit definition I just see a bunch of inverse limits entangled with quotients and localizations. I don't think inverse limit commutes with localization, does it?

Comment: @kwan: what (non-trivial) localizations? Since $x \in M$ we know that $\mathfrak{m}$ is *maximal* in $A$, so only quotients are arising in the limit process. You are absolutely correct that inverse limits do not generally commute with localization (e.g., $\mathbb{Z}[[x]] \otimes_ {\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q}$ is the subring of $\mathbb{Q}[[x]]$ consisting of series with bounded denominators), but that is not relevant since no nontrivial localizations are arising in your setup. 

Comment: @Boyarsky: I don't know what you mean by non-trivial localization. I can see how to prove it if A and B were local, but if they aren't, localizations are not trivial.

Comment: @kwan: I meant localization at something other than units.  The point is that when computing the *completion* of the localization at a *maximal* ideal, there is no need to invert anything new: one just forms the inverse limit of quotients $B/M^n$ (and similarly for $A$). Here we use the evident fact that $B/M^n \rightarrow B_M/(M B_M)^n$ is an isomorphism for maximal $M$ (and similarly for $A$) due to localization commuting with the formation of quotients. So you don't need to invert anything new when doing the calculation, regardless of whether $A$ or $B$ is local. 

Comment: @Boyarsky: That "evident" fact was precisely what I was missing. I'm shocked I haven't come across it before. Thanks for your help!

Comment: For all those who, like I, were wondering where to find this statement in the book: it is on page 157, in the proof of Theorem 19.5.